# How does Darth Vader sleep with his suit?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

Darth Vader wears his iconic black suit to help him to survive, covering his whole body.

When Darth Vader sleeps, does he remove his suit? And if not, how does he sleep and does he have a special place to sleep?

[image]

Comment: Why do you think he wouldn't be able to sleep in the suit? It may not be the most comfortable thing in the world, but it wouldn't be impossible.

Comment: The same way he sleeps after killing all that rebel scum: like a baby. (which apparently means waking up every once in a while to cry)

Comment: Forget sleeping. What about bathing?

Comment: On a huge pile of money, surrounded by beautiful women.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

His armor was painful up to the point he was barely able to sleep. To cope with this he meditates inside a liquid chamber to give himself some form of rest. And even when he slept he would awaken rather quickly due to horrifying visions he got about Padme.

Sources:

- Dark Lord: The Rise of Darth Vader
- Star Wars: Dark Times: The Path to Nowhere

Both are of course legends seeing the new canon hasn't filled in all the blanks yet.

Comment: This answer would be much better with quotes to back it up. You might also want to note that both sources are "Legends" canon, not official Lucasfilm canon

Comment: @Valorum agreed, but I don't have the comics on hand at the moment.

Comment: The newer canon Vader comics also show nightmares/weird dreams about Padme for what its worth.

Comment: Summing up: "How does he sleep?" "Badly"

Comment: It would not surprise me that Palpatine purposely made his suit painful to keep Vader on edge, grouchy, and generally unpleasant to artificially make him lean towards the dark side. Imagine if his suit gave him a feeling of bliss all the time? Wouldn't make a very good Sith lord at that point.

Comment: @Nelson Palpatine actually did that on purpose, the reason to why got answered a little while back even. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237563/does-pain-really-make-dark-side-force-users-more-powerful/237576#237576

Answer (score 85):

[In 'Rogue One' we see him suspended in a bacta tank](https://youtu.be/f-Mw8SeHC-U?t=9), entirely out of his suit. Presumably this is as close to restful sleep as he gets. Outside of that, there's [his meditation chamber featured in 'The Empire Strikes Back'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpQsk9cGpIA) which allows him to at least remove the helmet, and as the name suggests; meditate.
Keep in mind though that Vader is never "comfortable" or "restful". He's a raging inferno of constant agony and hatred. He may not ever truly "sleep".

Comment: the no sleep: "no rest for the wicked" resonates and real-life villains often slept weird hours and/or had trouble sleeping. i am not even a world-class villain but not being able to sleep certainly affects my mood.

Comment: I had to be up at 5AM this morning to monitor some stuff at work. So, yeah, in my small non-Sith way I can kind of relate to how he feels. ... (DEATH TO THE JEDI!!!!!!!!!!!) ... Yeah... :-)

Comment: You know, it never occurred to me that this scene directly contradicts the statement at the end of RotJ where Luke insists that he'll die if his helmet is removed, since we know of at least 2 incidents where removal of his helmet was not fatal.  Maybe it's only fatal because he was already dying from the Emperor's force lightning he absorbed earlier?  But in any case how would Luke know that anyhow?  It's not like there's a lot of prior examples in SW history of people in a Vader-like preservation suit, or of the effects of Sith force lightning...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Seems like there are plausible explanations. Bacta tanks are well established as being used in caring for severe injuries. It's not much of a stretch that one could keep Vader alive outside his suit. The meditation chamber may be specially built to provide additional life support. Yes, there's a few seconds while the chamber is opening before his helmet is back on, but A) force fields exist, and B) it was a very short time frame. As for Luke, his knowledge of the suit may be spotty, plus he doesn't really have time to search for a bacta tank or meditation chamber.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman My assumption about the meditation chamber (though I can't back it up with sources) is that it was pressurized with whatever air is sufficient for him to breath in the same way that his helmet does. As for how Luke would know that he would die, Darth Vader's condition and life preserving armor may be common knowledge that Luke would have known

Comment: Reading this answer makes me realize for the first time that the scene in ESB with Luke rehabilitating in a bacta tank is *yet another* foreshadowing of Luke following his father's path.

Answer (score 3):

in the Star wars movies we can see that Darth Vader have his own personal chamber made to assist him with the equipment /suit he wears as well as, for resting/meditation purposes. and also that Jedi/Sith, especially those trained to use the force having mastered it, don't need the same sleep requirements regular People need. They can "sleep" sitting straight up, on top of harder elements and they can do energy from the force to help them stay awake. The expanded universe, description books, gives more examples of Jedi/Sith sleeping or measures they take.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Legends canon novel *Shadows of the Empire* loosely following the story of the game of the same name describes a spherical "hyperbaric medical chamber" within Vader's residence on Imperial Center as it's referred to at the time which provides a "supermedicated and oxygenated field" in which Vader is able to survive without his armour.

This may be identical to or a larger version of a chamber we see on the *Executor* a couple of times in *Empire Strikes Back* where Vader tends to sit when not offing subordinates or taking calls from the Emperor. In one of these scenes just before the Battle of Hoth General Veers sees Vader's bare head from behind just before his helmet is lowered into place.